# Removing custom error from MessageBag Laravel

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I am trying to display a custom error message when the user who is trying to log in isn't registered in my website. I have this code for that.

```
if (!(User::where('nickname',$request->input('nickname'))->exists())) {

    // adding a custom error if user with such nickname doesn't exist

    $errors = new MessageBag;

    $errors->add('noExist', 'User with such nickname doesnt exist');

    return view('login')->withErrors($errors)->with('title','Login');

}
```

The error prints, but i want to remove it from my MessageBag, so it won't be displayed after a refresh. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't return a `view()` in a `POST` method; redirect back to the `GET` version, the error will display once, and upon refresh/re-submit, the error won't show again (unless you trigger it again)

Comment: Can you please show an example of redirecting back to `GET` version?

Comment: Sure, for example `return redirect("/login")->withErrors($errors);`. As long as you have a route that matches `/login` (I assume the login screen uses that route) and you use `->withErrors()` on the `redirect()`, it should display them on the subsequent `GET` request

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome; I'll convert to an answer, just a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return a `view()` in a `POST` method, like the Controller function handling a login attempt, any subsequent refreshes will simply re-submit the form. For this reason, the `ErrorBag` won't refresh as you'd expect (return to default state). To get around this, use a proper `redirect()` to handle re-rendering the `view()`:

```
// return view('login')->withErrors($errors)->with('title','Login');
return redirect("/login")->withErrors($errors);
```

`$errors` will be passed from the `POST` request back to the `GET` request handling the display of the `login` view, and on refresh, will be cleared.